# Can typescript extend the Array.prototype with methods that use the element type parameter?

Tags: generics, typescript, prototype

That was a very long title to describe something quite simple.

```js
interface Array<T> {
  sortBy<T, K>(keyFunction: (t: T) => K): T[];
}
```

.

```js
export namespace util {
export function sortBy<Element, Key>(array: Element[], keyFunction: (t: Element) => Key ): Element[] {

    var arrayCopy = array.slice();

    var mapped = arrayCopy.map(function(el, i) {
      return { index: i, value: keyFunction(el) };
    });

    mapped.sort(function(a, b) {
      return +(a.value > b.value) || +(a.value === b.value) - 1;
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let indexed = mapped[i];
        array[i] = arrayCopy[indexed.index];
    }

    var result = mapped.map(function(el){
      return arrayCopy[el.index];
    });

    return array;

}
}
```

.

```js
Array.prototype.sortBy = function(keyFunction)  {return util.sortBy(this, keyFunction)}
```

Here I am implementing some sample code from MDN to sort by an array key instead of comparison function, and attempting to patch the Array prototype (comments on whether this is a good idea or not are expected) with it.

However, when I call it, Typescript can't verify the proper argument types of keyfunction, and thus a cast is required to prevent a compiler error:

```js
it('should sort in-place', () => {
    var list = [{a: 'z', i: 2}, {a: 'x', i: 0}, {a: 'y', i:1}];
    // all good
    list.sortBy(<Function>(obj) => obj.i);
    expect(list.map((obj) => obj.a)
               .join('')
    ).toBe('xyz');
})


it('should sort in-place', () => {
    var list = [{a: 'z', i: 2}, {a: 'x', i: 0}, {a: 'y', i:1}];
    // Error TS2339: Property 'i' does not exist on type '{}'
    list.sortBy((obj) => obj.i);
    expect(list.map((obj) => obj.a)
               .join('')
    ).toBe('xyz');
})
```

Is there any way I can change this definition to work? Interestingly, calling `util.sortBy(array, function)` (i.e. as a function, not a method) has type parameters working correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interface declaration's sort function is creating a new `T` (`sortBy<T, K>`) disconnected from the `Array`'s `T`. Should be `sortBy<K>` and reuse the `Array`'s `T`.

## Correct Declaration

```
interface Array<T> {
  sortBy<K>(keyFunction: (t: T) => K): T[];
}

var list = [{a: 'z', i: 2}, {a: 'x', i: 0}, {a: 'y', i:1}];

// Okay
list.sortBy((obj) => obj.i);
```

Comment: but were you able to *implement* `sortBy` with the `T` type parameter?

Answer (score 2):

I just want to clarify how the implementation works. The type parameters on the implementation need not match the interface declaration, and can include the array type:

```
interface Array<T> {
   sortBy<K>(
      keyFunction: (t: T) => K
   ): T[];
}

Array.prototype.sortBy = function <T, K>(
   keyFunction: (t: T) => K
): T[] {
   ...
};

...

const array = [] as Something[];
const sorted = array.sortBy(x => x.SomeProperty);
```